# Wordpress - How to update user password using REST API

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

I am using `wordpress` as well `woocommerce` for my web store and also using `woocommerce REST API` for `Android app`.

I have used `WP REST API` and `JWT Authentication for WP-API` plugins for user authentication and login through rest api.

Now when I am using below api to change password

```
https://www.my-domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/<id>
```

getting below error

> { "code": "rest_cannot_edit", "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed
>   to edit this user.", "data": { "status": 401 } }

I don't know why am getting this error as authentication is done once at time of login. Can any one please help me?

Comment: See dock. http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/users/

Comment: I already did it. @AmitVisodiya

Answer (score 9):

Create your custom api

**URL**

https://yourdomain/api/change_password.php

**Parameter**

```
user_id:10
password:123456  //current password 
new_password:123456
```

Create folder **api** in root and create file change_password.php

**change_password.php**

```
<?php
include '../wp-load.php';

$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$new_password = $_REQUEST['new_password'];

if(empty($user_id)){
    $json = array('code'=>'0','msg'=>'Please enter user id');
    echo json_encode($json);
    exit;    
}
if(empty($password)){
    $json = array('code'=>'0','msg'=>'Please enter old password');
    echo json_encode($json);
    exit;    
}
if(empty($new_password)){
    $json = array('code'=>'0','msg'=>'Please enter new password');
    echo json_encode($json);
    exit;    
}
$hash = $user->data->user_pass;
$code = 500; $status = false;
if (wp_check_password( $password, $hash ) ){
    $msg = 'Password updated successfully';
    $code = 200; $status = true;
    wp_set_password($new_password , $user_id);
}else{
    $msg = 'Current password does not match.';
}




$json = array('code'=>$code,'status'=>$status,'msg'=>$msg);
echo json_encode($json);
exit;

?>
```

its working 100% for me try it

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. If you have performed all the steps mentioned on the plugin's documentation page, then there might be a problem with the account you're using to get the token.

Below is a video I created which details the whole installation / setup process for the plugin. Try following the steps I outlined and test again.

https://youtu.be/Mp7T7x1oxDk

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your .htaccess file by adding the following lines

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

and your wp-config.php by adding

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secret-key');
```

do not forget to pass your JWT_token in header API call, like

```
*Authorization : 'Bearer ' + YOUR_JWT_TOKEN*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a session-token/bearer/nonce with your ajax call. Here you've got the specific docs of interest:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication